# Как корректно вставить условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю ответ от сервера и на его основе выводу на страницу результаты поиска. в значениях  может приходить null. Если приходит null, то на странице нужно вывести пустой блок. Пробовал прописать тернарный оператор для ip - получаю абракадабру на странице. Как правильно описать условие?

```
if (response.length > 0) {
        response.forEach(function (item) {
          resulList += '<div class="table-row" data-id="' + item.id + '">' +
            '<div class="table-cell"><input type="checkbox" name=""></div>' +
            '<div class="table-cell">' + item.full_name + '</div>' +
            '<div class="table-cell">' + item.category__name + '</div>' +
            '<div class="table-cell">' + (item.ip) ? item.ip : "" + '</div>' +
            '<div class="table-cell">' + item.domain_name + '</div>' +
            '<div class="table-cell">' + item.hardware_purpose + '</div></div>';
        })
      }
```

Comment: response.length > 0 тоже не нужен, кстати) forEach и так ничего не сделает если массив пустой.

Comment: Да, от ошибки, если там будет что-то неитерируемое или null/undefined вас этот if всё равно не спасет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выучить приоритеты операторов https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Ваши строки

```js
... +
'<div class="table-cell">' + (item.ip) ? item.ip : "" + '</div>' +
...
```

эквивалентны

```js
(... + '<div class="table-cell">' + item.ip) ? (item.ip) : ("" + '</div>' + ...)
```

А вам надо написать

```js
'<div class="table-cell">' + (item.ip ? item.ip : "") + '</div>' +
// или даже проще
'<div class="table-cell">' + (item.ip || "") + '</div>' +
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то вам нужно вот эту часть кода `(item.ip) ? item.ip : ""` заменить на `(item.ip || "")` (тут тернарный не нужен), так как этим враппом в выражение вы четко указываете приоритет выполнения, а на данный момент у вас происходит изначальное вычисление всего до знака `?`, становится условием истинности и выводит результат вычисления `item.ip + всё после окончания тернарного оператора`.